# sort python variable to match another variable

Tags: python, mysql, database, algorithm, sorting

I do not know python to well, however I have a variable which has at least 100 values stored inside. The name is self.data

It is currently being ordered like this. **self.data.sort ()**

This sort() is sorting the values down by number for example 1,2,3

however I have created a database which will store variables in a particular order. how can I get the python to order the variables in that order.

for example db variables are

`customer ID
5
6
4
1`

self.data.sort()= 1,2,3,4...

i want help creating a function which will sort the variable to match the database.

self.data.customSort()=5,6,4,1...

Comment: Could you fix the code format? Just press *Ctrl+K* before you enter the code. I really don't understand you so I can't help you to edit.

Comment: ive editted it, and clarified a few details @KevinGuan

Comment: When you say the database has them in a specific order, how does the database maintain that order?  Is there an "order" column?  Is the order in which the rows were inserted into the database?

Comment: the database has them in a specific order, i insert them in the database in the order i want using a script. these are temp values which should delete them self after the variable self.data has arranged the variables in there to the database @BrendanAbel

Comment: it is actually very complex data which is being processed.. a simpler solution for me would be how can I overwrite self.data with the data in the database.@tmoreau

Comment: One does not generally rely on a database to store records in a particular order. Instead an order is imposed at the time of retrieval with the ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

You can create a compare function, let's see an example:
We want to sort every element in an array only if they are less than 5. So if a element is < 5 it will go to the 'left'. Fist of all we have to create a compare function that return -1 (true), 1(false) or 0.

```
def mySort(a):
   if a < 5:
       return -1
   elif a > 5:
       return 1
   return 0

lst = [6,8,3,4,68,1,2]
lst = sorted(lst, key=mySort)
```

print(lst)

output:
[3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 68]

As you can see now the array is sorted with my function mySort, you can use your special 'sort function' in order to follow your database structure. Hope that this will help